# Loading data from Parse server into a model file in an array.

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I want to load data from parse server into a model file in an array called posts but i don't know how.

Here is the code :

```
struct Post
```

{
    var createdBy: User
    var timeAgo: String?
    var caption: String?
    var image: UIImage?
    var numberOfLikes: Int?
    var numberOfComments: Int?
    var numberOfShares: Int?

```
static func fetchPosts() -> [Post]
{
    var posts = [Post]()

    var usernameArray = [String]()
    var avaArray = [PFFile]()
    var dateArray = [Date?]()
    var picArray = [PFFile]()
    var titleArray = [String]()
    var uuidArray = [String]()


    let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
        if error == nil {
            usernameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            avaArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            dateArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            picArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            titleArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            uuidArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

            // find related objects
            for object in objects! {



                usernameArray.append(object.object(forKey: "username") as! String)
                avaArray.append(object.object(forKey: "ava") as! PFFile)
                dateArray.append(object.createdAt)
                picArray.append(object.object(forKey: "pic") as! PFFile)
                titleArray.append(object.object(forKey: "title") as! String)
                uuidArray.append(object.object(forKey: "uuid") as! String)
            }

        }
    }

     return posts
}
```

}

struct User
{
    var username: String?
    var profileImage: UIImage?
}

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I am a beginner, so how to go around on doing this.

Comment: I just want to load all the data from parse into the array posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
static func fetchPosts() -> [Post]
{
    var posts = [Post]()

    var usernameArray = [String]()
    var avaArray = [PFFile]()
    var dateArray = [Date?]()
    var picArray = [PFFile]()
    var titleArray = [String]()
    var uuidArray = [String]()


    let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
        if error == nil {                
            // find related objects
            if let returnedObjects = objects {
                for object in returnedObjects {
                    usernameArray.append(object["username"] as! String)
                    avaArray.append(object["ava"] as! PFFile)
                    dateArray.append(object.createdAt)
                    picArray.append(object["pic" as! PFFile)
                    titleArray.append(object["title"] as! String)
                    uuidArray.append(object["uuid"] as! String)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return posts
}
```

In order to append data to your `posts` you need to 
- Convert PFFile to UIImage
- Create a User object with the UIImage
- Add the User object to your `posts`

```
if let avaPicture = object["ava"]! as! PFFile {
    avaPicture.getDataInBackground({ (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            if image != nil {
                // Create your User object with UIImage here
                let user = User()...

                // Add the new user and other data to your `posts`array
                ...
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: That retrieves data from server and appends it into arrays. How about appending these arrays into the posts array which has it's own properties : struct Post
{
    var createdBy: User
    var timeAgo: String?
    var caption: String?
    var image: UIImage?
    var numberOfLikes: Int?
    var numberOfComments: Int?
    var numberOfShares: Int?

Comment: So i will just ignore other strings i created and focus on the posts array?

Comment: It's up to you. Ask yourself what data you are going to use then you have an answer.

Comment: Thanks lawliet that helped me a lot :)